# Error 1 The name 'WriteAt' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a game in C# that runs on my cmd on Windows and I need to be able to write to any part of the box to do that. I found `WriteAt` used extensively for this purpose, however it doesn't seem to work in VS 2010. I get the error: "The name `WriteAt` does not exist in the current context"

I have the default:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
```

at the top of my code. So why can't I use `WriteAt`?

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace GamePCL
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Clear();

            for (int x = 0; x < 24; x += 2)
            {
                WriteAt("█", x, 0);
                WriteAt("█", x, 30);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where are you using `WriteAt`?

Comment: I think you need to use `Console.WriteLine()`.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a custom method that calls SetCursorPosition internally?

Comment: I don't think WriteLine() lets you choose a position.

Comment: "Are you sure it's not a custom method that calls SetCursorPosition internally?"  That might be it, lemme check... And yes that's it! thank you! Been trying to figure this out for hours...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call a method without an object or type prefix, as in this case `WriteAt()` (as opposed to for example `Console.WriteLine()`, which is called on the `Console` type), the method must exist in the current context, i.e. in the current class.

You copied that code [from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition(v=vs.110).aspx) without copying the relevant method:

```
protected static void WriteAt(string s, int x, int y)
{
    try
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(origCol+x, origRow+y);
        Console.Write(s);
    }
    catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException e)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```